# Angular scope won't update on apply

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't update scope variable that I'm handling in ng-repeat

```
 <div ng-controller="MapViewCtrl">
            <a class="item item-avatar" ng-href="#/event/tabs/mapView" >
                <img src="img/location.jpg"/>
                <span class="input-label">Locations Of event</span>
                <div    ng-repeat="item in positions" style="font-size: 12">{{item.address}}</div>
            </a>
        </div>
```

My controller looks like:

```
 $scope.closePage = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var lng = markers[i].position.A;
            var lat = markers[i].position.k;
            var address = "";
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            $scope.$apply( $scope.geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng},function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if (results[0]) {
                        address =results[0].formatted_address;
                        var location ={
                            address: address
                        }
                        $scope.positions.push(location);
                    }
                }
            }));
        }
        $state.go ('eventmenu.createevent');
    };
```

Do you have any suggestions how to update  positions variable?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a function containing the code to [$scope.$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply), rather than just the code:

```
$scope.geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng},function(results, status) {
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
                address =results[0].formatted_address;
                var location = {
                    address: address
                }
                $scope.positions.push(location);
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Also note that apply is called in the callback from the geocoder. That tells Angular that it needs to check for changes in the scope.